# Can't figure out a triple joint with group by

Tags: sql, join, group-by, json-arrayagg

I want to get the Creators of Artworks, GROUP BY by their role.
I find a way to have the list of the Creators with their role, for each Artwork.

```
SELECT 
    JSON_OBJECT('id', a.IDartwork, 'creaDate', a.artworkCreationDate, 'length', a.length, 'summarize', a.summarize) AS artwork,
    (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', c.IDcreator, 'name', c.creatorName, 'role', r.roleName))
     FROM AMEGA_creator c 
     JOIN AMEGA_artwork_creator ac ON c.IDcreator = ac.IDcreator 
     JOIN AMEGA_role r ON r.IDrole = ac.IDrole
     WHERE ac.IDartwork = a.IDartwork) AS creators
FROM 
    AMEGA_artwork a;
```

But I can't get to use the `GROUP BY`. I get the error:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

I can't find a solution. I want a result like that :

```
artworks         creators
 <art1>          < <"director", <crea1, crea26>>, <"writer", <crea5, crea12>> >
 <art2>          < <"drawer", <crea23, crea8>> >
```

Here is the MLD structure :

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: Not sure that a subquery is needed here. What RDBMS are you using (mysql, oracle, postgres, sql server, snowflake, teradata, etc)? I think Oracle, Mysql, and DB2 all have a `json_arrayagg()` function but possibly the help we can give will be dependent on which platfrom you use.

Comment: I use **Mysql**.
I also try a group by with the final structure i want : <br/>

`SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('role', r.roleName, 'crea', JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', c.IDcreator, 'name', c.creatorName))))
        FROM AMEGA_creator c 
          JOIN AMEGA_artwork_creator ac 
         ON c.IDcreator = ac.IDcreator 
         JOIN AMEGA_role r
         ON r.IDrole = ac.IDrole
         WHERE ac.IDartwork = 2
         GROUP BY ac.IDrole;` <br/>But i get a 'invalid use of group by' error.

Comment: I think you need to join in `AMEGA_artwork()` in your subquery FROM clause and then only have the subquery, moving your `JSON_OBJECT()` into that SELECT statement and then add a `GROUP BY JSON_OBJECT(...)` at the end. Your subquery in your SELECT is returning multiple rows and isn't correlated to your `Amega_Artwork` table so you end up an error (more than one row returned from subquery) and even if that didn't error, you would have a cartesian product which is definitely not what you are after.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i'm not sure to understand. AMEGA_artwork is already called, no problem joining a second time in the subquery ? I use a different alias for it ? I don't understand either how to make the subquery only after. I get the point of the multiple rows from the subquery, but don't figure out and see in my head how to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of a guess on how this should look from my comment. Essentially somewhere in your SQL (either via correlated subquery's where clause or through a single SELECT's FROM clause) you have to establish a relationship between `AMEGA_artwork` and the rest of the tables. You went with a correlated subquery which is a good choice. The issue though is that for each `AMEGA_artwork` record there is more than one aggregated `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` result in that subquery. Normally this would be fine, but because your subquery is in your `SELECT` clause you can only have a single record come through for each `AMEGA_artwork` record. Otherwise you get that error.

I've switched this to a single FROM clause to establish the relationships between your table, and then a single JSON_OBJECT leading to your `artwork` output column and an aggregated JSON_ARRAYAGG() of the remaining column.

```
SELECT 
     JSON_OBJECT('id', a.IDartwork, 'creaDate', a.artworkCreationDate, 'length', a.length, 'summarize', a.summarize) AS artwork,
     JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', c.IDcreator, 'name', c.creatorName, 'role', r.roleName)
FROM
    AMEGA_artwork a
    JOIN AMEGA_artwork_creator ac 
       ON a.IDartwork = ac.IDartwork
    JOIN AMEGA_creator c     
       ON c.IDcreator = ac.IDcreator 
    JOIN AMEGA_role r
       ON r.IDrole = ac.IDrole        
GROUP BY artwork;
```

The different here is that we establish the relationship between `AMEGA_artwork` and `AMEGA_artwork_creator` in the FROM clause.

What you will likely see on running this is more than one record for each `artwork`. Which one is correct, or which one you want to keep, or how you want to further aggregate the data to reduce it to a single record, will be up to you.

Comment: Working on revising my write up (sql isn't changing). I incorrectly thought you didn't have a correlated subquery, but in fact you do. That was a good step and I missed it.

Comment: Edit has been made. Sorry again for missing that you had correlated your subquery.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer. It does aggregate well the rows into one array. But, their always a but else it is not funny, i'm wondering if i can also group the Creators by role. I try this :  <br />`JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('role', r.roleName, 'crea', JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('id', c.IDcreator, 'name', c.creatorName)))) as creators,<br />`. But i have an error on GROUP clause.

Comment: And i want a structure like this :     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  `artworks         creators
 <art1>          < <"director", <crea1, crea26>>, <"writer", <crea5, crea12>> >
 <art2>          < <"drawer", <crea23, crea8>> >` I'm sorry, i can't display it well in the comments. It is visible in the top question. Do you think it is possible ? Maybe i need to subquery the creator part ?